# sulogin cannot read /dev/tty1 permission denied

Tags: boot, 16.04, fstab

When booting up Ubuntu 16.04, I'm getting this:

> Press enter for maintenance( or type Control-D to continue)

and when pressing enter, I get this error:

> sulogin cannot read /dev/tty1 permission denied

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure your `/etc/fstab` is all correct and reboot. I would recommend commenting out all lines except the essential ones (by putting # at the beginning of the line) and trying to reboot. If it works, try uncommenting the lines one by one and rebooting between each try to see which lines is the problem.

Comment: Thanks. This was a good hint. In my case, it was a mount entry in `fstab` that referred to an external HDD. It appears that if that drive was in power-save mode while the computer rebooted it did not connect (over USB connection) and this caused the boot process to fail.
 
My solution was to add the option `noauto` to the respective entry in `fstab` (this required, of course, taking care of mounting the external drive manually as it was not mounted automatically anymore - but at least it did not prevent the machine from booting).

Comment: This answer also helps in the context of the following question from the Odroid platform forum: 
https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=99&t=25892

Comment: How would one edit /etc/fstab if they cannot get past the password prompt at boot?

Comment: +1 Also encountered a similar problem today after rebooting a server it reported `invalid checksum recovering block 0 in log` and `EXT4-fs error loading journal` after googling it looked as if it had to do with corrupt file system. However this wasn't the real reason I had issue. Because right after pressing `Enter` it would display the real issue: `sulogin cannot read /dev/tty1 permission denied`. in my case there was a line in the `/etc/fstab` file that caused this. This answer saved me :)

Comment: For me I had to enter maintenance mode and run `fsck` to fix the non-root file system disk, then after a reboot everything worked again. Before I figured that out, commenting out the fs in /etc/fstab helped to confirm it was that disk causing issues.